# how to run webspec and watij

Tags: java, watij, webspec

I have the following code...

```
public class first
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        WebSpec spec = new WebSpec().safari();
        spec.safari().open("http://www.google.com"); //opens google.com in Safari
    }
}
```

written in eclipse.

WebSpec is underlined in red giving an error saying "cannot be resolved to be a type"
I assume this is because some of the libraries are not in the right spot? 
I have tried many different things.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Is Eclipse showing any error while importing?

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to include all .jar's included in the webspec download in your library. There are .jar's in the lib folder and also one .jar in java\dist of webspec. Eclipse allows you to import libraries by highlighting your project then Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries (tab).